# Blackberry TabScroll and Focus problem

Tags: blackberry

I'm a newbe for Blackberry and finding it quite difficult, I'm working on the TabControl example. I have changed the tabs to scroll. Now when i scroll through tabs the focus changes and as soon as the focus shifts to the other tab, the data for that tab appears.

I want to make these tabs clickable only, though they shall scroll but should change only on click.

And also when i use UIApplication.getApplication.pushScreen(someScreen) in the tabs, this someScreen appears out of the tabs, whereas i want to show this screen below the tabs only.

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override onFocus(int) to not do anything when focus is moved. (You may or may not have to override touchEvent to handle an actual CLICK event).

You can push a screen into tabs that is not part of the tabs already. If you want something new to appear, try switching managers within the screen instead.